# Tab content don't take all the place

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I use bootstrap 4, I have a left menu.
When I click on one element, i display a tab.

I do an ajax call to get the thymeleaf fragment

Tab content don't take all the space

```
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
   <div class="row h-100">

      <div class="col-lg-2 my-auto">
         <div th:replace="fragments/left-menu :: LeftMenu('none')"></div>
      </div>

      <div id="main" class="col-lg-10 main">
         <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
             <li class="nav-item">
                 <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#productTypesTabs" th:text="#{productTypes}">Product Types</a>
             </li>
         ...
         </ul>

         <div class="tab-content">
             <div id="productTypesTabs" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
                 <div id="productTypesFragment"></div>
             </div>   
             ....
         </div>

      </div>
      ....

   </div>

</div>
```

Content of the fragment for productTypesFragment
https://pastebin.com/cDRqVViz

why it don't take all the space, don't understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is the class container

Change

```
<div id="productTypesTabs" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
    <div id="productTypesFragment"></div>
</div>
```

to

```
<div id="productTypesTabs" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active"><br>
    <div id="productTypesFragment"></div>
</div>
```